nginx proxy_pass redirects instead of proxying
I have an nginx configuration below (playground). A curl to /foo/bar returns a 301 Moved Permanently to /bar. Adding a trailing slash to the location fixes the problem. Why?
I'm not seeing anything the proxy_pass or location docs that suggest a 301 should be returned. Could a double slash in http://localhost:7777//bar be causing a redirect?
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:7777/;
}

$ curl http://localhost/foo/bar -I

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
Location: /bar


You should use localhost /foo/ to correctly translate /foo/bar to /bar. I do not know the source of the 301 status, perhaps localhost:7777 is generating it because of the missing /.

@RichardSmith I updated the question with the curl command and the nginx Server response header (or lacktherof). Not sure it means anything.

Your curl command doesn't clarify was it back-end service generating the redirect or not. Ask your back-end directly, as if it was reverse proxied: curl -I -H 'Host: localhost' http://127.0.0.1:7777/foo/bar, and see what happens. // I feel like the service at port 7777 wants bar to be mounted to root, e.g. to be at /bar, and doesn't expect to see requests to /foo/bar, so it redirects to the "correct location"... in which case, the old advice comes up to mind, never change a path when reverse proxying... The below answer by Tero Kilkanen is basically about the same thing.

This should be a comment, but the comments space is limited....

There is NOTHING in the config you have shown us that will result in a redirect.
Where is the rest of the configuration for the site?
Why do you assume/assert that the issue is in nginx?
Did you check the logs on the origin server? What did they say?
Did you check the nginx logs? What did they say?
Did you amend the nginx logging to identify when requests were handled locally rather than passed to the origin?


The redirect is likely created by your application where you proxy the request to.
This redirect happens because the application expects a different path in the request than it is given.
Therefore you need to configure the application's root URL as it looks from outside.
